# Get UL list content with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I need to get content from a UL list and then be able to use that to email.  But I'm stuck on getting the ul list in jquery.  I've searched and found the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#send").click(function() { //When trigger is clicked...
            var optionTexts = [];
            $("#thelist").each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).text()) });
            var text = '"' + optionTexts.join('"<br/> "') + '"';

            $("#result").append(text);

        });
    });
```

but this returns all contents inside the page :S
Here's my ul list:

```
<ul id="thelist">
  <li style="height: 65px; display: list-item; ">
    <ul>
      <li class="botHeader">
        "Evelin dice"
                <span>14:37:52</span>
      </li>
      <li class="botMsg">
        "Hola, bienvenido"
      </li>
    <ul>
  </li>
  <li style="height: 26px; display: list-item; ">
    <ul>
      <li class="userHeader">
        "Usted dice"
                <span>14:37:59</span>
      </li>
      <li class="userMsg">
        "Hola como estas"
      </li>
    <ul>
  </li>
  <li style="height: 39px; display: list-item; ">
    <ul>
      <li class="botHeader">
        "Evelin dice"
                <span>14:37:59</span>
      </li>
      <li class="botMsg">
        "Gracias por preguntar, todo bien"
      </li>
    <ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<a href="#" id="send">enviar</a>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: What _precisely_ are you looking to get out of the list? "I need to get content from a UL" is too vague

Comment: What is it that you need exactly, the HTML inside the UL, or the text present on every LI? Or other...

Comment: "and then be able to use that to email." I need the whole block, everything inside that ul so I can send it as the body of an email message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the whole lot in one go, and without any temporary variables:

```
$('#result').append(
    $('#thelist').find('li').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('ul').length === 0;
    }).map(function(i, e) {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join('<br/>')
);
```

You have to only consider the `<li>` elements that don't have any `<ul>` descendents.

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/JVS7d/

Comment: this gave me an Uncaught TypeError: Object and then it has the Ul content as the error lol..

Comment: So I remove the .appendTo from that line?

Answer (score 1):

First, you're markup is invalid. You're missing the closing `</ul>` on your inner lists.
Second, you just need to add `li` to your selector for your `$.each(...)` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#send").click(function() { //When trigger is clicked...
        var optionTexts = [];
        $("#thelist li").each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).text()) });
        var text = '"' + optionTexts.join('"<br/> "') + '"';

        $("#result").append(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: that selector won't work - it'll get confused by the nested lists.

Comment: actually no, because that'll produce one entry per item in the outer list, not one for each leaf node.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what the OP was asking then.

Answer (score 0):

looks to me you should change the `$("#thelist").each(function...` to `$("#thelist ul li").each(function...`

Comment: I've tried that and for some odd reason it duplicates the li's

Comment: yeah, because you have nested `<ul>` so the selector finds both the top level and second level `<li>` elements.

Comment: right that's why i put just #thelist, i also tried putting a div around it and using that id but that didn't do it either..