# Display the content of <ul> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

**Why this html script doesn't work well? 
 I can see the content of the h1 tag to the browser but
 i can't see the the content of the ul tag.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Miletracker</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Miletracker</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home" data-transition="none" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#add" data-transition="none" data-icon="plus">Add Run</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**I found it.**

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
   <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
       <h1>Miletracker</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="navbar" >
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#home" data-transition="none" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#add" data-transition="none" data-icon="plus">Add Run</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>            
</div>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6gzqdrk9/   I think so everything is working fine...Please check the jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

`navbar` is behind `#home`. `#home` has `position: absolute` and it covers the rest of the page.

Just add `position: relative;` to `navbar`

Comment: Or you can add  navbar into #home :)

Answer (score 0):

according to the jquery ul tags

```
$('#result').append(
$('#thelist').find('li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('ul').length === 0;
}).map(function(i, e) {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join('<br/>')
```

);

demo at here [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/JVS7d/) and

[This link may helpful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761139/get-ul-list-content-with-jquery)